# Wmic output into variable

Tags: batch, wmic

Am trying to write the output of this command into a variable, but can't quite get the syntax to work...

My WMIC query is:

```
wmic PATH SoftwareLicensingProduct WHERE "ProductKeyID like '%-%' AND Description like '%Windows%'" get LicenseStatus
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the output from running your command?

Comment: The output is: 
LicenseStatus
1


I want to capture the 1 in a variable

Answer (score 2):

#### The output is: `LicenseStatus 1`, I want to capture the `1` in a variable

Use the following batch file:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=2" %%i in (`wmic PATH SoftwareLicensingProduct WHERE "ProductKeyID like '%-%' AND Description like '%Windows%'" get LicenseStatus`) do set _variable=%%i
@echo %_variable%
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.

Comment: Thanks for the your suggestion, when I run this as a batch file I receive "No Instance Available".

When I run the wmic query separately I get the output I expect.

Comment: @WeeYin I've just noticed an error in my answer (I had `%%1` instead of `%%i` which has been corrected). Please try again.

Answer (score -1):

Just use:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=2" %%i in (`wmic PATH SoftwareLicensingProduct WHERE "ProductKeyID like '%%-%%' AND Description like '%%Windows%%'" get LicenseStatus`) do set _variable=%%i
@echo %_variable%
```

It's basically the code from the first answer, but with doubled per cent signs.

BB