# WMIC in for-loop

Tags: windows, batch, wmic

I'm trying to get WMIC output into a variable so I can process it further.

I have made a test batch file to illustrate the problem:

```
wmic PROCESS where "commandline like '%%teststr%%'" get     Processid,Caption,Commandline
for /F "usebackq" %%R in (`wmic PROCESS where "commandline like '%%teststr%%'" get Processid,Caption,Commandline`) do echo OUTPUT is %%R
```

Having called this batch I get the expected output for the first line, but `invalid GET expression` for the second.

Since the first line does work I think there is something wrong with my quoting - could someone please shed a light on this? I triple-checked it syntactically and it all seems correct to me according to this other question: [Wmic output into variable](https://superuser.com/questions/974272/wmic-output-into-variable)

Edit1: %teststr% is just a string to filter, it could be javaw for example to look for certain java instances.

Edit2: Exact output is:

```
Caption    CommandLine                                                                                                                  ProcessId
javaw.exe  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "J:\tools\sonst\jEdit\jedit.jar" -reuseview -background -nogui  5152
javaw.exe  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_91\bin\javaw.exe" -jar "J:\tools\sonst\jEdit\jedit.jar" -reuseview -background -nogui  11504
javaw.exe  "c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\javaw.exe"  -jar "j:\tools\online\JBinUp\JBinUp.jar"                            16336
WMIC.exe   wmic  PROCESS where "commandline like '%javaw%'" get Processid,Caption,Commandline                                           18740

Invalid GET Expression.
```

BB

Comment: What is `%%teststr%%`?

Comment: Why do you have `but ´` at the end of your first command? And `Commandlin` is not spelt correctly.

Comment: What is the output of `wmic PROCESS where "commandline like '%%teststr%%'" get Processid,Caption,Commandline`?

Comment: Please [edit] the question, fix the mistakes and add the extra information.

Comment: Done - was just a paste error, in the batch file was correct.

Comment: I still want the output from the `wmic` command for testing.

Comment: Done. It's the output of the whole batch, lines 1-5 come from the first line of the batch, last line from the second which I try to debug,

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### I get `invalid GET expression` for the second command.

```
for /F "usebackq" %%R in (`wmic PROCESS where "commandline like '%%teststr%%'" get Processid,Caption,Commandline`) do echo OUTPUT is %%R
```

You need to escape the `,` (commas) in the `for` expression, using the `^`  Escape character:

```
for /F "usebackq" %%R in (`wmic PROCESS where "commandline like '%%teststr%%'" get Processid^,Caption^,Commandline`) do echo OUTPUT is %%R
```

Notes:

- You might also want to add `skip=1` to the  `for` command to skip the header.
- You will get an extra blank line at the end of the `wmic` output.
- Use `findstr` to strip the blank lines from `wmic` output, as follows:

```
for /F "usebackq" %%R in (`wmic PROCESS where "commandline like '%%teststr%%'" get Processid^,Caption^,Commandline ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do echo OUTPUT is %%R
```

Test batch file:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
wmic process where "Commandline like '%%note%%'" get Processid,Caption,Commandline
for /f "usebackq" %%r in (`wmic process where "commandline like '%%note%%'" get Processid^,Caption^,Commandline ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do echo OUTPUT is %%r
endlocal
```

Example output:

```
F:\test>test
Caption                   CommandLine                                                                                                                            ProcessId
GSNotes.exe               "E:\GoldenSectionNotes\GSNotes.exe"                                                                                                    8864
LiberKeyPortabilizer.exe  "E:\LiberKey\LiberKeyTools\LiberKeyPortabilizer\LiberKeyPortabilizer.exe" /app="E:\LiberKey\Apps\Notepad++\Notepad++LKL.dat"  /lkpend  12324
notepad++.exe             "E:\LiberKey\Apps\Notepad++\App\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"                                                                               11948
WMIC.exe                  wmic  process where "Commandline like '%note%'" get Processid,Caption,Commandline                                                      1364

OUTPUT is Caption
OUTPUT is GSNotes.exe
OUTPUT is LiberKeyPortabilizer.exe
OUTPUT is notepad++.exe
OUTPUT is cmd.exe
OUTPUT is WMIC.exe
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [findstr](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) - Search for strings in files.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) - Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes.